# How to inherit XDG_SESSION_TYPE in systemd units?

Tags: systemd, environment-variables, services, wayland, systemd-unit

My current desktop environment: Plasma Wayland.

Many GUI applications can't be launched from within Emacs daemon (started by e systemd unit) unless `XDG_SESSION_TYPE` is set to "wayland". It's not a problem when Emacs is started normally, but that environment variable isn't inherited as a service.

I tried editing the unit:

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'XDG_SESSION_TYPE=$${XDG_SESSION_TYPE} exec /usr/bin/emacs --fg-daemon'`

But this isn't effective during the initial (after logging in) life time of the service.

Current unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Emacs text editor
Documentation=info:emacs man:emacs(1) https://gnu.org/software/emacs/

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'XDG_SESSION_TYPE=$${XDG_SESSION_TYPE} exec /usr/bin/emacs --fg-daemon'
ExecStop=/usr/bin/emacsclient --eval "(kill-emacs)"
KillMode=process
Environment="XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx" "GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx" "LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8"

SuccessExitStatus=15

Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: `$$` before XDG_SESSION_TYPE looks like a bug to me.  Even grepping for `'\$'` in /usr/lib/systemd/ on my machine doesn't show any unit files with $$ (and a few that use just a single `$` for variables in `sh -c` scripts, including `"$XDG_SESSION_TYPE"` for org.Shell.wayland.service and org.gnome.Shell.x11.service).   Can't comment on the rest of it, except to say that setting a variable to itself doesn't seem particularly useful if it doesn't already contain a value.   Maybe try just `export XDG_SESSION_TYPE` if you're sure it's already defined as a shell var rather than an env var.

Comment: or maybe just set it in the Environment= line.

Comment: @cas
`ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'export XDG_SESSION_TYPE ; exec /usr/bin/emacs --fg-daemon'` doesn't work so I don't think it's a shell variable.

And setting `Environment="XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland"` directly would sacrifice portability (incorrect in X11 sessions).

Comment: Sometimes what you need to do to get something working is more complicated than just setting a single environment variable. That's what scripts are for. So write a script that detects whether it's running under X or Wayland, sets XDG_SESSION_TYPE appropriately and then runs emacs.  Also needs to cope with various errors and unexpected/undesirable conditions like not being under either X or Wayland.   Run that from ExecStart.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set it directly

`Environment="XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland"`

And ignore the X11 session.